# I need to get a users manager property, use that to get the managers object and then pull her mail property into a variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a termination script that will be doing a lot of tasks. I am having issues with getting the managers email address from AD with `Get-ADUser` into a variable I can then insert into Office 365 forwarding email address. I thought I could pull the Managers name into a variable and then use `Get-ADUser` to pull her/his email address into another variable. Unfortunately I am fairly new to PowerShell and am trying to teach myself.

**Here is my code:**

```
$User = Write-Host 'user ID you want to get the managers email of'

$Manger = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties Manager | Select-Object @(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties displayName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by nesting two `Get-ADUser` commands as follows:

```
(Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $user -Properties manager).manager -properties mail).mail
```

Comment: That got me what I needed! Thanks a lot I was banging my head on my desk WAY too loudly :)

Comment: The final product looks like this '
$User = Read-Host 'user ID you want to get the managers email of'

$managerEmail = (Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $user -Properties manager).manager -properties mail).mail'

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = read-host -Prompt 'whatever'
Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties Manager -outvariable aduser |
  Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties displayName -outvariable manager
```

I'm not sure if this achieves exactly what you need, since I don't have AD module.