# How to convert a manager-DN to an email address inside a variable with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need an existing variable to be filled with additional information which has to be resolved for every 'element' in this variable.

This is what populates my variable:

```
$a = Get-ADUser -Filter {Manager -eq 'User1'} -Properties Name, Department, Manager, Mail | Select Name, Department, Manager, Mail
```

This is what my variable `$a` looks like:

```
@{Name=User1; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User1@mail.com}
@{Name=User2; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User2@mail.com}
@{Name=User3; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User3@mail.com}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to "convert" the Managers DN to the Managers email address and add this back to the variable `$a`.

My desired result would look something like this:

```
@{Name=User1; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User1@mail.com; ManagerMail=User1@mail.com}
@{Name=User2; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User2@mail.com; ManagerMail=User1@mail.com}
@{Name=User3; Department=IT; Manager=CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local; Mail=User3@mail.com; ManagerMail=User1@mail.com}
```

Right now I'm struggling to reach my goal...

I know how to resolve the Managers DN to the Managers email address (something like this):

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'CN=User1,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=local' -Filter * -Properties Mail | Select mail
```

I'm having a hard time getting the specific Managers DN out of my initial variable to resolve it to the Managers email address, and after that of course to get it back in again, in this variable `$a`.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511137/i-need-to-get-a-users-manager-property-user-that-to-get-the-managers-object-and/40511370#40511370

Answer (score 0):

```
$Manager = Get-ADUser -Identity 'Manager1' -Properties Mail

$a = Get-ADUser -Filter {Manager -eq 'Manager1'} -Properties Name, Department, Manager, Mail | 
         Select-Object -Properties Name, Department, Manager, Mail, @{Name='ManagerMail'; Expression={$Manager.Mail}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That info absolutely nailed it. I added it to my line and it instantly worked:

```
$a = Get-ADUser -Filter {Manager -eq 'User1'} -Properties Name, Department, Manager, Mail | Select Name, Department, Manager, Mail, @{Name="ManagerMail";Expression={(Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $_ -Properties manager).manager -properties mail).mail}}
```

Thank you James C.